# RabbitMQ - Should I ever use persistent messages on a mirrored queue?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm running the new RabbitMQ 3.12. I know I should be using quorum queues, but right now it's not possible. So, I'm still running a mirroring policy on my queues. They're all durable too.

From what I gather from the documentation and playing around with it, when a node joins or rejoins a queue mirroring group (I avoid using the word quorum to avoid confusing the concepts), the first thing it does is dump all of its previous data on this queue, and joins unsynchronized (and then it can either automatically or manually get synchronized over time).

So is there any point in sending persistent messages to such a queue then? Even if the messages survive a node reset, they'll just get dumped anyway, wouldn't they?

Maybe I'm missing something in the vast field of knowledge known as RabbitMQ.

Comment: sending persistent messages to a mirrored queue can be very useful if your application requires strong durability guarantees. The mirroring ensures availability and fault tolerance of the queue itself, while persistence ensures that individual messages are not lost in the event of a node restart. The use of persistent messages in a mirrored environment doesn't necessarily lead to data being "dumped" on rejoining; rather, it ensures that the state of the queue is consistent across the cluster.